# Object reference error when installing an extension from visual studio gallery

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I uploaded an extension to the visual studio online [gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5dd55421-d916-4035-8dfd-49d017e26eea), but when I install it through visual studio I get this exception at the end of the installation

[image]

This error only happens when I install it from visual studio. If I download the vsix and double click it to install, I do not see this error.

Any pointers to why this might be happening? Right now I don't have any way to debug this or get logs for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bad value in the "Getting started guide" field of the vsixmanifest. I discovered this by attaching the vs debugger to the instance of visual studio that was throwing the error and observing the stack trace (after enabling [break when CLR exceptions thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) in the debugger).

This was the exception in the debugger

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.Implementation
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.UI.ExtensionManagerWindow.NavigateToGettingStartedGuide(Uri gettingStartedGuideUri)
```